# Preload image with Javascript and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a big problem with images in javascript embedded aplications. I want make a preload image but I don't know how the browser works.

See this simple example: [code](https://jsfiddle.net/f8fy7mdj/3/)

```
var colors = [
    "http://www.robolaranja.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/Primeira-imagem-do-filme-de-Angry-Birds-%C3%A9-revelada-2.jpg",
    "http://imguol.com/c/noticias/2013/12/13/13dez2013---esta-imagem-mostra-a-nebulosa-de-caranguejo-um-iconico-remanescente-de-supernova-na-nossa-galaxia-vista-do-observatorio-espacial-herschel-e-do-telescopio-hubble-uma-nuvem-de-gas-e-poeira-1386961235961_956x500.jpg",
    "http://wallpaper.ultradownloads.com.br/121350_Papel-de-Parede-Imagem-Abstrata_1920x1200.jpg"
]

var currentDiv = "div2";
var count = 0;
var lenght = colors.length;
var timeForNextImage = 0;
var preloadOk = false;

setInterval(function() {

    count ++;
    if (count > lenght) count = 0;

   var date = new Date();
   var time = date.getTime();

    if  (time > (timeForNextImage - 3000) && preloadOk == false) {
        preLoad();
    } else if (time > timeForNextImage) {
        play();   
    }



}, 300);

var play = function() {

    if (currentDiv == "div2") {
        $('#'+currentDiv).css("visibility", "visible");
    } else {
        $('#div2').css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
    var date = new Date();
    timeForNextImage =  date.getTime() + 10000;
    preloadOk = false;

    $("#lbl").text("div atual: "+currentDiv);
 };

var preLoad = function() {  

      if (currentDiv == "div1") {
        currentDiv = "div2";      
    } else {
        currentDiv = "div1";
    }

     $("#" + currentDiv).css("background-image", 'url('+colors[count]+')');
    preloadOk = true;
};
```

How you can look, I  do a preload, in theory.. but, the browser only processes my image when I put it in the stage ?

What if I change the z-index attribute, it renders again?

Comment: Are you trying to achieve image rotation in every 3 seconds?

Comment: `css("visibility", "hidden")` => new browser lazy load css hidden element; so a div with background image implicit `height: 0px;` is usually better if you don't use JS

Answer (score 2):

You return `preloadOK = true` but the image doesn't load. That's not a preloader.

To make a preloader you can play with `new Image()` object or with `load()` event.

```
var images = new Array()
function preload() {
  for (i = 0; i < preload.arguments.length; i++) {
    images[i] = new Image()
    images[i].src = preload.arguments[i]
  }
}
preload(
  "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-001.jpg",
  "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-002.jpg",
  "http://domain.tld/gallery/image-003.jpg"
)
```

See more

[3 Ways to Preload Images with CSS, JavaScript, or Ajax](https://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/)

Comment: Ok, but, how the browser works ? It is processes the image when we put in the stage?

Comment: I will try this strategy with javascript load, thanks!

Comment: When you put the background image, the url is updated but you return true next line. To control asynchronous loaders as ajax or images, you need a deferred to wait to load some asynchronous resource. Otherwise, with that methods you can achieve the same without a deferred. But if you feel interesting in what is and how it works the deferred, take a look: https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to preload an image is to just create an image tag and set the url as the src. You don't have to attach it to the DOM to make the request.

```
var preLoad = function() {  
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = colors[count];
};
```

Comment: Is it works only external images or local images to?

Comment: hmm, and how I can use this 'img' in the background,  ? for example: 
$('<img/>').attr('src', img).load(function() {
   $('#bkpId').css('background-image', ???);
});

Comment: Once you preload an image using the above, the browser caches it, so when you need to show the image you just set its URL as the src for the visible image tag, and the browser will load the image from the cache, without actually making a new request.

Comment: hmmmm, I understand now. Thanks